# Is FibonacciHeap a min-heap? how to find max using FibonacciHeap?

Tags: java, fibonacci-heap

My Java project is to use Max Fibonacci heap to find top nth most popular hashtags.
The record can be like this:

```
#saturday 5 
#sunday 3 
#saturday 10 
#monday 2 
#reading 4 
#playing_games 2
3
```

But Fibonacci heap only have find min function.
What is the difference between 'Fibonacci heap', 'Min Fibonacci heap' and 'Max Fibonacci heap' ?

My idea is to use function extractmax() n times to get the top n. but I don't know what is Max Fibonacci heap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching between min and max heaps is trivial, you just change the comparator.  A heap is a heap, whichever direction it's working in, the algorithm doesn't change.

Finding the maximum element is just finding the minimum element except you change the ordering.

Comment: Sorry. I don't get you. Fibonacci heap can use findmin(). Because the min is the root. Is there a Fibonacci heap that store max in root?

Comment: Sure.  It's exactly the one you get when you just change the `<` to `>` in the Fibonacci heap code and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using min heaps in the structure, use max heaps.